# Registry items being removed with script

Tags: powershell, registry, onedrive

Good morning all,

I have an interesting issue with the code put together below, but first a bit of a background.

Onedrive doesn't like working with domain roaming profiles. When OneDrive is installed for a user it will install OneDrive on the PC's "Appdata\local" folder instead of for the whole PC. This means it will use that installed version for that particular PC until it is updated to a newer version. If a user is to hotdesk from another PC where their version of Onedrive is older or newer Onedrive will fail to work for them on that PC as it pulls in account information from the roaming profile within the registry. The registry compares the version in the roaming profile to the version installed in Appdata/Local and fails to start.

The script below put together by me and the help of others (with a shoutout to [tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)) is supposed to do the following:

- Delete two DWords within "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive"
- Remove a Key within "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive" which corresponds to the version number for example 18.0289.187
- Delete any new folders within "LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive"

It will perform the last task because when you delete the 2 DWords and Key from the Onedrive key and start OneDrive it will create another folder within "LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive" which is around 100MB. Ideally I would like to place this script in group policy to be run on login of every user.

```
$oneDriveInstallDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\appdata\local\Microsoft\OneDrive"
$Versionarray = 13..20

if (Test-Path $oneDriveInstallDir) {
  Stop-Process -Name "OneDrive" -Force
  $currentVersion = (Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive -Name "Version").Version 
  Remove-ItemProperty HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive -Name "Version" -Force
  Remove-ItemProperty HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive -Name "CurrentVersionPath" -Force
  Remove-Item "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\$currentVersion" -Force
  Start-Process $oneDriveInstallDir/OneDrive.exe
  }  
  Get-ChildItem "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive" -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $item = $_
    $item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] -and (
        $Versionarray | Where-Object { $item.Name.Contains($_) }
    )
} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Stop-Process –Name invalidprocess -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError;

If ($ProcessError) {

    Write-Warning -Message "Some of these folders are in use.";
    }
```

**The Problem**

When the script is run it will ask if I want to carry on and delete the items requested. I don't really want it to ask, even with the force commands it still asks. The major issue is it will then start to delete all of the items within the registry OneDrive key which it shouldn't do. I have tried going through a debug before asking but can't find the reason. Please see an example of the files it's attempting to delete below:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\ClientConfigTelemetryTimeStamp
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\MigrationCompleted
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\StandaloneUpdaterSafeMode
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\UpdateXMLRescanTime

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Did the answer of @TobyU not solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

**The prompt**

Use the `-Confirm:$false` switch with your `Remove-ItemProperty` and / or `Remove-Item` commands to get rid of the prompt.

**The deletion of the OnDrive Registry Hive**

If there is no value set for `$currentVersion`, the follwing part of your script will delete the OnDrive Registry Hive:

```
Remove-Item "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\$currentVersion" -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can install it with

```
OneDriveSetup.exe /allusers
```

which installs it in "C:\Program Files (x86)" once per system, instead of in AppData per user.

This is MSFT's recommended installation process.  This installation will also remove previous versions installed in AppData.